# Strategies for high throughput transactional processing

Tags: java, performance, transactions

I have a system that has strict "once and only once" requirements with respect to what it does. It is an event driven system with middleware that cannot guarantee once and only once messaging (it will flag any given message as "redelivered" if it is in doubt over whether this is a redelivery). The "once and only once" processing essentially comes down to the state of our core domain object, i.e. it's a fairly standard setup whereby....

1. messages arrive
2. business logic is executed
3. state is updated
4. outputs are generated and sent to downstream systems

3 has to ultimately hit a database (books and records), 4 can take a variety of forms but all are some sort of messaging to external systems. There are a variety of other flows too but they all come down to this sort of style of processing. All messages will operate on a single instance of the core domain object and therefore the processing is amenable to pinning that instance to a single jvm.

My Q is quite general, possibly too general but I'll ask anyway. Namely what strategies/patterns one can employ to drive throughput upwards while maintaining the guarantees required? Alternatively, what are the main gotchas that will kill performance?

For example, one line of thought is around avoiding any persistence in the critical path which comes down to a question of how to maintain consistency of the in memory state without needing to refresh from the database.

You can assume it is possible to scale out through some partitioning strategy but that aspect is out of scope of the q. The Q is about how to scale up the throughput of a single node in such a system.

Note this is java/oracle in a big enterprise setting so niche hardware (e.g. exadata & friends or some fancy network kit) is fine.

Answer (score 2):

A lot depends on what guarantees you need in terms on how failure is handled.  You can achieve messaging rates over one million per second, using flat journal files and/or redundant servers for persistence.

The main pattern you need is an actor pattern. To increase throughput you need to be able to batch data transparently as part of your design.  Personally I like working with direct ByteBuffers (most of the data is not on the heap) as they are a light weight way of dealing with large amounts of data which can be copied and read/written to NIO Channels easily.  I have written my own parsing/logging libraries for gc-less input/output.

Another useful strategy is pre-allocating and recycling objects. This can help eliminate the risk of a GC by not creating garbage (or creating only a very small amount which can be collected once per day)

The trick is not releasing the results of your processing until your persistence guarantees have been met. (The simplest approach is to not have any guarantees and say the last few transactions can be lost and will be deal with manually)

The main things which can kill performance are

- IO, you want this to be asynchronous.
- Excessive Locking
- creating lots of objects will result in poor cache efficiency (as new objects effectively scroll out your useful data) Recycled object can stay in cache.
- GC can hurt you worst case latency. If you only care about throughput, this doesn't matter.
- make sure you warm up your code.  By default you need to perform 10,000 invocations of a method (or have a loop which iterates this many time) in a short period to trigger it to compile.  If you have low latency, but not high throughput system, large portions of critical code may not get compiled.
- make sure you are on decent hardware and have a recent version of Java.  Older machines and older versions of Java can be quite a bit slower.

Comment: level of guarantee is tbd, I suspect it will be "never lose anything but if you do, make sure it's not v often and make sure we know we've lost it". Manually triggered replay via injection of synthetic message is fine.

Comment: IMHO There is only what you kept a record of and what you have lost. So you can't know what you have lost. If you must keep everything, you need to ensure all data is kept redundantly. i.e. to a second server and to disk I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

- *what strategies/patterns one can employ to drive throughput upwards while maintaining the guarantees required?*

Not sure I can easily correlate this question to the `"once and only once" requirements` you refer to, but I'll give it a shot anyway.

event driven / non blocking approach, which I believe already "kind of" in your flow judging by `messages arrive`. Imagine self contained / immutable components that are able to receive messages and react depending on the type/payload of the message, Let's call these components `actors` for a moment. Then your flow would become:

#### messages arrive

to the actor

#### business logic is executed

in the stateless `method` that corresponds/matches to that message's type

#### state is updated

`state` can be a flat file / RDBMS / NoSQL / memory that only depends on your architecture => that is driven by the business.

So, that same `method` could call `store.update()` or simply send another message ( e.g. UpdateStatus ) to a StatusActor, so we don't lock/block [that would depend on whether "update => generate => send downstream" needs to be atomic or not]

#### outputs are generated and sent to downstream systems

now actor sends another message (e.g. GenerateOutput ) to another actor that generates the output, and sends another message ( e.g. SendDownstream ) to another actor.

- *Alternatively, what are the main gotchas that will kill performance?*

Blocking / Locking and.. Premature Optimization

Answer (score 0):

That's "fairly" easy, "just" make your operations idempotent and ack all operations.

Comment: sure but the Q is about *how* you implement something as opposed to a high level principle. Idempotency is an easy term to toss about (middleware vendors do it all the time) but one often sees it implemented as kicking the can down the road to the next system.

Comment: That is _how_, it's just not in code.
The idempotency is to make sure that the "-and-only-once" part is made sure of, and the acking is the "once".
To avoid applying the same operation twice it's fairly easy to just either enforce ordering of operations and use a monotonically increasing operation identifier, and discard all operations with an identifier lower or equal to the last operation performed. IF that is not possible you need to store all operations and deduplicate against those.

Comment: this is the performance side of it though, enforcing ordering implies sequenced messages and consumption of them in a deterministic order and processing the message in a given thread. Alternatively it's means some distributed cache and the cost involved in putting something into it. Q is what ways exist to sidestep (at least some of) this?

Comment: Then you need to keep track of messages that have been already processed, meaning to be able to uniquely identify them. It's all about space/time tradeoffs.